# Correctness of algorithm for rearranging persons according to height?

Tags: algorithm, correctness

You are given two array, first array contain integer which represent heights of persons and second array contain how many persons in front of him are standing who are greater than him in term of height and forming a queue.

- heights are unique means no two person can have same height.

Example-

A: 3 2 1

B: 0 1 1

It means in front of person of height 3 there is no person standing, person of height 2 there is one person in front of him who has greater height then he, similar to person of height 1. Your task to arrange them Ouput should be. 3 1 2

My approach

1.Sort persons according to their frequency(no. of taller person).

2.Now fix the position of each person in appropriate position. for example:

3 1 2 4

0 2 1 0

after sorting

3 4 2 1

0 0 1 2

now we see that first and second person are at right place so we move third person to it's right position that is 2nd(base index 1) as he has only one taller before him.

3 2 4 1

0 1 0 2

now for 4th person we just place it at 3rd position

3 2 1 4

0 1 2 0

final answer.

I think it has O(n^2) complexity.Can we do better, and what about correctness of this algorithm?

Comment: So if I understand correctly, the person at the head of the line will stay there. Unless you assume that no two people have the same height. Because if two people can be the same height then you don't know if `0 0 1` means that the first person is taller than the second, or the same height as the second.

Comment: all are of different height,sorry for that.

Comment: Your algorithm looks correct. Not sure about the complexity. The sorting of course is O(n log n). The second pass of rearranging *might* be O(n^2). It might be possible, however, to do it with a single sort.

Comment: I do not understand your example. Just tell me in simple words why is 3 2 1 not a valid answer to your first example? How do we know that height 1 guy is taller than height 2 guy as in your expected output 3 1 2?

Comment: @NaveedHasan: The example is poorly worded. Perhaps this helps: The person with height 3 is at the head of the line. The person with height 2 has one person ahead of him who is taller. The person with height 1 has one person ahead of him who is taller. So the answer must be 3,1,2. If it were 3,2,1, then the person with height 1 would have 2 people taller than him in line. The puzzle is worded poorly, too. But it's an interesting puzzle once you figure out what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Jim Mischel: That makes sense. I was going in very different directions before your explanation. One possibility I considered was that the heights are sort of height-ID's, e.g. height-id 3 = 5 feet etc. Anyway thanks!!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174796/puzzle-find-the-order-of-n-persons-standing-in-a-line-based-on-their-heights?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

The left-most value of sequence B is always 0-- it's the person standing in front of the queue and there's noone before him.

Whenever the sequence B has a sequence of consecutive 0-s on the left, that portion of the queue is sorted in itself.

So, when you have, say k consecutive 0-s to the left and the value t at the (k+1)-st position, (t necessarily <= k), 
the rightmost t of those k people are taller than the one standing at that (k+1)st posn.

Eg.:
suppose

A: '5' '3' '6' '9' '1' '4'
B:  0   0   0   2   0   1

the height of the leftmost 3 are '5' < '3' < '6',

and since the value of '9' is 2, the one of height '9' is shorter than those in 
the rightmost 2 and taller than the other among these 3. So, just move '9' to 2 positions left and update its value to 0.

You can solve this in **O(n)** time using a linked list implemented on an array.