# 406(LeetCode). Queue Reconstruction by Height

Tags: javascript, algorithm

**So here is the question:**

https://leetcode.com/problems/queue-reconstruction-by-height/

Suppose you have a random list of people standing in a queue. Each person is described by a pair of integers (h, k), where h is the height of the person and k is the number of people in front of this person who have a height greater than or equal to h. Write an algorithm to reconstruct the queue.

Note:
The number of people is less than 1,100.

Example:

```
Input:
[[7,0], [4,4], [7,1], [5,0], [6,1], [5,2]]

Output:
[[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]
```

And here is my answer using javascript:

```
var reconstructQueue = function(people) {
var result= [];
people.sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]).sort((a,b)=>b[0]-a[0]);
for(var i=0; i<people.length; i++) {
    result.splice(people[i][1], 0, people[i]);
}
return result;
};
```

It can pass the test above, but Why didn't it pass all the tests in Leetcode? Can anybody help me?

Comment: I'm not an expert in javascript. Might be that this expression `people.sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]).sort((a,b)=>b[0]-a[0]);` has a guarantee to preserve order on elements that are equivalent according to the comparator-function? Otherwise using this piece of code is quite prone to errors. To be honest: for a language that is as little standardized as javascript, you're putting your head way too far above the parapet. I'd recommend merging those two comparators into one.

Comment: Note that `people.sort((a,b)=>a[1]-b[1]).sort((a,b)=>b[0]-a[0]);` is the same as `people.sort((a,b)=>b[0]-a[0]);`, you're simply *resorting* with a different ordering rule. The second sort does *not* operate on sublists.

Comment: @Paul JavaScript, the programming language, as described by ECMA standard 262, currently 6th edition, is extremely standardized. Don't confuse "JavaScript" with "The browser APIs that can be used in JavaScript".  That's like confusing C++ for some random library it uses.

Comment: The sort function can sort all the tests as I've tried, so problem shouldn't be the sort function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Puzzle: Find the order of n persons standing in a line (based on their heights)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19174796/puzzle-find-the-order-of-n-persons-standing-in-a-line-based-on-their-heights)

Answer (score 2):

You are applying the sort two times and its not correct because the first time you order the queue by 1 index and then you order by 0 index. You have to order the queue one time and order by 1 index if a and b have the same height or order by 0 index if they have different height
You sort function will be

```
people.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a[0]==b[0]){
        return a[1]-b[1];
    }
    else{
        return b[0]-a[0];
    }
});
```

Using arrow function

```
people.sort((a,b)=>a[0]==b[0]?a[1]-b[1]:b[0]-a[0]);
```

Comment: The sort function can sort all the tests as I wanted, I still can't find where the problem is although; thanks for your answer so much!

Comment: I've tried the code with the test examples, the problem is not the sort function; it's the splice() function which works different in firebug and chrome's console; thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need a better sort function and sort first index 0 descending and index 1 ascending.

```
people.sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0] || a[1] - a[1]);
```

ES5

```js
var reconstructQueue = function(people) {
        var result = [];
        people.sort(function (a, b) {
            return b[0] - a[0] || a[1] - a[1];
        });
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            result.splice(people[i][1], 0, people[i]);
        }
        return result;
    },
    data = [[7, 0], [4, 4], [7, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [5, 2]],
    result = reconstructQueue(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // [[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]
```

ES6

```js
var reconstructQueue = function(people) {
        var result = [];
        people.sort((a, b) => b[0] - a[0] || a[1] - a[1]);
        for (var i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            result.splice(people[i][1], 0, people[i]);
        }
        return result;
    },
    data = [[7, 0], [4, 4], [7, 1], [5, 0], [6, 1], [5, 2]],
    result = reconstructQueue(data);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result)); // [[5,0], [7,0], [5,2], [6,1], [4,4], [7,1]]
```

Comment: It didn't pass the all tests in Leetcode also and I still can't find figure out the reason; anyway, thanks for your answer so much!

Comment: @ChuckWang, maybe you need ES5 style.

Comment: I've tried the code with the test, the problem is not the sort function; it's the splice() function which works different in firebug and chrome's console; and so I think I need to figure out how splice function works actually; thanks so so much for your answer anyway!

Comment: [`Array#splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) should work fine on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution with runtime of 88 ms.

```
// sort people by height ASC, then sort people by order DESC
const sortPeople = (a, b) => {
  if (a[0] === b[0]) {
    return a[1] - b[1];
  } else {
    return b[0] - a[0];
  }
}

const reconstructQueue = (people) => {
  const output = [];

  people.sort(sortPeople);

  people.forEach(p => output.splice(p[1], 0, p));

  return output;
};
```